# problem in Doctrine Two Entities with many to many relationship , cli tool reports an error when creating schema (SchemaException)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, many-to-many, relationships

I created two Doctirne entities , which has many to many relationship together in between them. But when i trying to created the db tables from that schema , i am getting a weird exception which is a SchemaException saying "Table with *somename* already exists" but as i double checked the database , it does not contain any tables at all.  Please guide me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Entity Doctor

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="doctors")
 */
class Default_Model_Doctor
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Default_Model_Patient", inversedBy="doctors")
     * @JoinTable(name="doctors_patients",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="doctor_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="patient_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */

    private $patients;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->patients = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setName($string) {
        $this->name = $string;
        return true;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Entity Patient

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="doctors")
 */
class Default_Model_Patient
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $name;

    /** 
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Default_Model_Doctor", mappedBy="patients")
     */

    private $doctors;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->doctors = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setName($string) {
        $this->name = $string;
        return true;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

This is the error i receive from Doctrine cli tool when creating the Schema.

Please follow this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRdYU.png) for the screenshot i have attached which shows the error clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Change @Table(name="doctors") in your Patients model to @Table(name="patients")